# I can't zoom in and out with mouse while playing games in fullscreen mode

Tags: google-chrome, zoom, logitech-mouse

I updated Chrome to 58 and now it won't let me zoom in or out nor scroll the page with my mouse.

If I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> plus the mouse button it doesn't do anything while I'm in full screen mode. It was working fine with my mouse yesterday before I updated my Chrome.

How can I fix this?

I have tried everything and can't figure it out. No matter what Facebook game I play in full screen mode it will not let my mouse zoom in and out nor scroll. On all other pages it scrolls fine but not games in Facebook while in full screen mode.

Comment: `I have tried everything` Can you elaborate more on what you've tried?

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: Change the zoom level on another page on the same site (ie: facebook.com).  It should change the zoom level on all tabs to that site.

Option 2: Set the zoom level of Chrome before clicking the link to start the game.

Option 3: Click outside the game (but still within Chrome) to set the focus on the background.  Then Ctrl+Scroll should behave normally.